# How to prove this problem by using similarity of two triangles?

Tags: euclidean-geometry

I have this problem:

Let be given a right triangle $ABC$ $(AB<AC)$; $AH$ is altitude of the triangle, $BD$ is bisector of the angle $\angle ABC$. Let $E$ is projection of the point $C$ onto the line $BD$ and $M$ is intersection of point of two lines $AB$ and $CE$. Prove that $BA\cdot BM + CE\cdot CM = BC^2$.

[image]

I tried. We can see $BC=BM$ and $CE=EM$.  From
$BA\cdot BM + CE\cdot CM = BC^2$, we have
$$\dfrac{BA\cdot BM}{BC^2} + \dfrac{CE\cdot CM}{BC^2}=1,$$
then
$$\dfrac{BA}{BC} + 2\left( \dfrac{CE}{BC}\right) ^2 = 1.$$
We have
$\dfrac{BA}{BC} = \sin \angle BCA $ and
$$2\left( \dfrac{CE}{BC}\right) ^2 = 2\sin^2 \angle CBE = 2 \left (\dfrac{1 - \cos\angle ABC}{2}\right) = 1- \cos\angle {ABC} = 1 - \sin BCA. $$
Thus
$$\dfrac{BA}{BC} + 2\left( \dfrac{CE}{BC}\right) ^2 =\sin \angle {BCA} +  1 - \sin BCA = 1.$$

Another way,
We have
$$BA\cdot BM = BA\cdot (BA+AM) = BA^2+BA\cdot AM =   BA^2+  AD\cdot AC,$$
and
$$ CE\cdot CM = CD\cdot CA=(AC-AD)\cdot CA = AC^2 - AD\cdot CA. $$
Then
$$ BA\cdot BM  + CE\cdot CM = BA^2+ + AC^2 = BC^2.  $$

Comment: What’s the question? Your second proof seems to implicitly be using similarity.

Comment: I am sorry.  Maybe I've solved it